Dynamically select radio button in angular
I am trying to select radio buttons dynamically. Below is the code and stackblitz link. Unfortunately the button is always selected/checked. How can I toggle the radio button selection on the toggle button click.
example.component.ts
selected = false;

toggleSelection() {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
  }

example.component.html
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="selected" [checked]="selected">
    {{ selected }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

    <button
        (click)="toggleSelection()"
      >
        Toggle selection
      </button>


The problem is that you assign the [value]="selected" to the <mat-adio-button>.
Instead, you should assign [value]="true". Meanwhile, you don't need [checked] attribute as you apply the [(ngModel)] in <mat-radio-group>.
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="true">
    {{ selected }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

Demo @ StackBlitz

How to make it work if I remove the toggle button and move the action to the radio button? <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected" (click)="toggleSelection()">

For this scenario, you don't need the toggleSelection function to set the selected. With [(ngModel)], it will set the value with the selected <mat-radio-button>.

selectedValue: boolean | null = null;
selected = false;

toggleSelection() {
  this.selected = !this.selected;

  this.selectedValue = this.selected ? true : null; // Toggle selection

 between true and null
}

html
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="selected">
    {{ selected ? 'Selected' : 'Not Selected' }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<button (click)="toggleSelection()">
  Toggle selection
</button>


How to make it work if I remove the toggle button and move it action to the radio button? <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (click)="toggleSelection()">
